# implement javascript in django templates language

Tags: javascript, python, django, json, django-templates

```
{% with JSONContent as object %}{% include "_comments.html" %}{% endwith %}
```

JSONContent is a django model instant that I got by `$.get()` method.
"_comments.html" is an unrendered template for comments.
I want to render that template, and send it to the client by AJAX (so the revieved data is an  the rendered HTML from the template)
How do I do that?

Comment: You need to better explain what you are trying to do. What do you mean 'delivered by json'? If you mean that the server delivered the  json to the client via ajax then what you are saying doesn't make sense as templates are rendered by the server before they reach the client. If you have sent the Json to the server then you need to use simplejson to decode it to a python object

Comment: I'm trying to build an commenting system that gets comments without reloading the page ( like youtubes "see 10 more comments"). and you are right, it doesn't make sense... but how do I extract comments for a specific model instent?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are getting an instance of a model from an ajax request to the server, and you want to use that instance in the "_comments.html" template. Is that right? If so, you could instead render the template on the server and fetch the rendered HTML in the ajax request.

So, suppose you have a view called `fetch_new_comments` that handles the ajax request. Instead of getting a comment model and dumping it to JSON and returning that, the view might look something like this:

```
def fetch_new_comments(request):
  comments = ... # get whatever data you're using
  return render_to_response("_comments.html", {"comments": comments})
```

So this means that your ajax request would receive a chunk of HTML (instead of a JSON object), and insert that on the page. If you're using jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$.get("http://yoursite.com/fetch_new_comments/", function (resp) {
  $("#new_comments_container").html(resp);
});
```

Comment: but how do I compile the html and apply it to 'comments'?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. The ajax request sends a request to the server for the new comments, which causes the `fetch_new_comments` view to execute. `fetch_new_comments` gets some data from the database, stores it in the `comments` variable, and renders a template (_comments.html) which has access to the `comments` variable. The rendered template, which is a chunk of HTML, is returned as the result of the ajax request, and the Javascript code that issued the ajax request then inserts this chunk of HTML on the page.

Comment: Maybe if you're still confused you can show the _comments.html template and how you are getting the `JSONContent` that you mentioned in your quesiton.

Comment: I have changed the question, hope this is clear now, thank you for your time!

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why my answer doesn't answer your question. When you call `$.get`, is the request going to a URL that is part of your site? If so, the URL should return the rendered template instead of just the data in JSON form. More of your code would be helpful, e.g. the Javascript that calls `$.get` and the view that is returning the JSON object.

Comment: I found what I was looking for, it was the 'render_to_string', thank you for helping me though!